# How to determiine which dropdown was used

Tags: html-select

I have a form with more than one dropdown list, like this below. I can see how to get the ID's of each dropdown but I can't figure out how to get the one that was actually used. Would someone explain how to do that, please.

```
  <div>
   <select name="id[11]" class="pullDown" id="attrdrop0">
    <option class="pink" value="31`">No</option>
    <option class="pink" value="32">Yes (+$40.00)</option>
   </select>
  </div> 

  <div>
   <select name="id[10]" class="pullDown" id="attrdrop1">
    <option class="pink" value="31">No</option>
    <option class="pink" value="32">Yes (+$150.00)</option>
   </select>
  </div> 

<script>  
$(function () {
   $("#prices").change(function () {
     console.log('A change was made');
     CalculatePrice();  
  });
});  

function CalculatePrice() {
    var ttl_price = 0;
    var id = '';

    $(":input.select, :input").each(function() {
       var cur_price = $('option:selected', $(this)).text();
       ttl_price += cur_price;    

       id = $(this).attr('id');
       /*** What now ***/
    });  
    SetPrice(id, ttl_price);    
}  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the control as a parameter to CalculatePrice.

```
$(function () {
   $("#prices").change(function () {
     console.log('A change was made');
     CalculatePrice(this);  
  });
});  

function CalculatePrice(triggerObject) {
    var ttl_price = 0;
    var id = '';

    $(":input.select, :input").each(function() {
       var cur_price = $('option:selected', $(this)).text();
       ttl_price += cur_price;    

       id = $(this).attr('id');
       /*** What now ***/
       if (triggerObject.id) {...}
    });  
    SetPrice(id, ttl_price);    
}  
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't think that will do what I want. I tried it and it does display true in the CalculatePrice function but it doesn't identify the dropdown. The "#prices" is the form name and if I check the id variable in the CalculatePrices function, it just displays the form name. I need to know the dropdown ID. Is that possible?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your solution or I confused things with the initial code but before the code I showed is [code]<form name="prices" action="" method="post" id="prices">[/code] so when the change function is called, (this) is pointing to the form, not the dropdown. In CalculatePrice, the code then cycles through all of the elements in the form. I couldn't see another way of doing this short of creating a change function for each dropdown and that is an unknown number since the code will be on several pages.

Comment: I tried that with nodeName but it just gave select or option - no element ID. I found a post somewhere that said to use id instead of nameNode so I tried the following but it just displays "clicked." [code]$( "#prices" ).click(function( event ) {
       console.log( "clicked: " + event.target.id );
     });[/code]

Comment: How about binding event to every element of the form and use this pointer? Eg: $('#price *').change(...)

Comment: I ended up changing $(function () { to a named function and then adding an onchange command to each dropdown and it is working now. Thank you very much for sticking with this. I do appreciate it.